# Laravel form submit with route and controller

Tags: laravel

1.How can i get correct routing into form open phrase.

2.I wanted to generate the URL: dgrs/2014-31-01.

form in only view file: dgrs/show.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('action'=>'DgrsController@ddgr')) }}
   Select Date: 
   {{ Form::input('date', 'dgrdate', $dt, array('class' => 'input-md')) }}
   {{ Form::submit('View', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

routes.php

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), 'dgrs/(:date)', ['as'=>'ddaily', 'uses'=>'DgrsController@ddgr']);
```

DgrsController.php

```
public function ddgr($date)
{

    $dt=isset($date) ? $date : date("Y-m-d");   //date selection from user
    ...

    return View::make('dgrs.show', compact('dfinal', 'dt'));
    //dfinal is db query and dt is selected date back to show.blade.php
}
```

view is the form file: dgrs/show.blade.php

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with jQuery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

{{ Form::open(array('action'=>'DgrsController@ddgr' , 'id' => 'myFrm')) }}
Select Date:
{{ Form::input('date', 'dgrdate', $dt, array('class' => 'input-md' , 'id' => 'txtDate')) }}
{{ Form::submit('View', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#txtDate").change(function(){

        var baseUrl = "{{  URL::to("dgrs") }}" + "/" + $(this).val();

        $("#myFrm").attr("action",baseUrl);

    });

});

</script>
```

so what i have done is when ever date changes form action url is changes according to that date.

Comment: Error: throw new NotFoundHttpException;

Comment: you need to pass date as second parameter but you are passing date as form input that is difficult to generate url

Comment: i think you need to use JavaScript to change Form URL dynamically

Comment: Yes something like that, but how to do that?

Comment: asking about JavaScript ?

Comment: wait for some time will post in some minute

Comment: Same Error: NotFoundHttpException